# Is there a way to show only specific values in x-axis of an excel chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, gnuplot

In my problem, I have `0.1 0.2 0.5 1.0` on the x-axis and I want to plot my chart by showing only these values on the horizontal-axis. Is there anyway or any extension (like kutools) to make this happen in Excel? Or any other tool suggestion would be nice, like R, gnuplot, etc.

For example, in the following figure, you can see what I mean about the x-axis. Thanks in advance.

[image: An example chart]

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing sample data.

Comment: " I want to plot my chart by showing only these values on the horizontal-axis" - what else do you see? would be useful to post current status too and explain what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can either:
1) Use a line chart, which treats the horizontal axis as categories (rather than quantities).
2) Use an XY/Scatter plot, with the default horizontal axis "turned off" and replaced with a "helper" series with vertical values of 0 and horizontal values as desired in your dataset (this is my preferred method).

[image]

**EDIT:  Step by Step directions**

Here's the step-by-step method to achieve the result you referenced (and hopefully solves your problem).  Assuming the series {x, a, b, c, d} values:

```
x     y     a     b     c     d
0.1   0     60    70    81    90
0.2   0     55    67    82    91
0.5   0     53    65    94    98
1.0   0     52    62    97    99
```

1. Create an XY/Scatter Chart and add the four series {a, b, c, d} each as your Y/Vertical axis and the {x} series as your X/Horizontal axis.  Your chart will look something like this:

[image]

2. Now, add the {x} series as a fifth series with the {y} series for your Y/Vertical axis and {x} series as it's own X/Horizontal axis values.  It's colored orange in this sample.  This series will become your custom horizontal axis.

[image]

3. Delete your default X/Horizontal axis.  Simply select the axis and delete.  Alternatively, you can select the axis and format it with No Tick Marks, No Labels, and No Line.

[image]

4. Finally, format your {y} series to look like a default axis.  In this case I used my vertical axis format to mimic, so the series line format matched the color and line weight.  Also, since I needed vertical ticks at each marker, I used the Built-in "+" marker in the same color.  Finally, add data labels Contains X Value and format Label Position to Below and match color and font to your other axis.

[image]

Comment: Could the downvoter please provide some constructive criticism to help me improve the answer?