# How to show specific values in x-axis of an Excel scatterplot

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

How can I change the x-axis in Excel, so it only shows specific values. 
I would like the x-axis only to show the values of the corresponding x-value of my data. 
I have a image of how I would like the x-axis in the end of this post, if it is any help for understanding. 
Furthermore, I have put down a link to a similar question. The thing is that i do not understand the answer, and how the person fixed the problem.

[Image of how I would like it to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgFfe.png)
[Is there a way to show only specific values in x-axis of an excel chart?](https://superuser.com/questions/1407365/is-there-a-way-to-show-only-specific-values-in-x-axis-of-an-excel-chart)

Comment: What is it you do not understand about the answer? Can you not generate either one of the suggested charts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to show only specific values in x-axis of an excel chart?](https://superuser.com/questions/1407365/is-there-a-way-to-show-only-specific-values-in-x-axis-of-an-excel-chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the step-by-step method to achieve the result you referenced (and hopefully solves your problem).  Assuming the series {x, a, b, c, d} values:

```
x     y     a     b     c     d
0.1   0     60    70    81    90
0.2   0     55    67    82    91
0.5   0     53    65    94    98
1.0   0     52    62    97    99
```

1. Create an XY/Scatter Chart and add the four series {a, b, c, d} each as your Y/Vertical axis and the {x} series as your X/Horizontal axis.  Your chart will look something like this:

[image]

2. Now, add the {x} series as a fifth series with the {y} series for your Y/Vertical axis and {x} series as it's own X/Horizontal axis values.  It's colored orange in this sample.  This series will become your custom horizontal axis.

[image]

3. Delete your default X/Horizontal axis.  Simply select the axis and delete.  Alternatively, you can select the axis and format it with No Tick Marks, No Labels, and No Line.

[image]

4. Finally, format your {y} series to look like a default axis.  In this case I used my vertical axis format to mimic, so the series line format matched the color and line weight.  Also, since I needed vertical ticks at each marker, I used the Built-in "+" marker in the same color.  Finally, add data labels Contains X Value and format Label Position to Below and match color and font to your other axis.

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer, @dav, I was going to say exactly the same, but you've saved me the trouble.

Comment: Of course, this is an XY Scatter chart, with X values spaced out proportionally to their numerical value. The link posted by @Camilla is actually what an Excel line chart would give you, with points evenly spaced horizontally, despite 0.1 and 0.2 being closer together than 0.5 and 1.0. I would avoid the line chart for this, since it distorts the X values, and if anyone wanted to interpolate, it would lead to errors.